# Deriving autocovariance of time series

Tags: time-series

Consider the following AR(1) process:
$$
y_{t}=\phi_{1}y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}
$$
I am asked to compute the autocovariance betweem $y_{t}$ and $y_{t-s}$.
Write down the DGP for $y_{t-s}$ which is:
$$
y_{t-s}=\phi_{1}y_{t-s-1}+\epsilon_{t-s}
$$
Write down the covariance as:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
cov\left(y_{t},y_{t-s}\right) & =E\left(\left(\phi_{1}y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}\right)\left(\phi_{1}y_{t-s-1}+\epsilon_{t-s}\right)\right)\\
 & =E\left(\phi_{1}^{2}y_{t-1}y_{t-s-1}+\epsilon_{t}\epsilon_{t-s}+\phi_{1}\epsilon_{t-s}y_{t-1}+\phi_{1}y_{t-s-1}\epsilon_{t}\right)\\
 & =\phi_{1}^{2}E\left(y_{t-1}y_{t-s-1}\right)
\end{alignat*}
Where the last expression follows from the white-noise properties
of $\epsilon.$ I know that the correct answer is in fact $\sigma_{y}^{2}\phi_{1}^{s},$
but I am unable to get to it. Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: The issue might become obvious by considering the smallest non-trivial case where $s=2$ and writing everything out: $$y_t=\phi y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=\phi\left(\phi y_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1}\right)+\epsilon_t.$$ Use the basic algebraic rules of covariance along with what you already know.  Notice the factor of $\phi^2$ lurking there: that will guide you.

Answer (score 2):

Just a first tip:

In $y_{t} =\phi_1y_{t-1} +\epsilon_t$ replace $y_{t-1}$ by $\phi_1 y_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1}$, then replace $y_{t-2}$ and so on until you have an expression with $y_{t-s} $ on the right hand side.

Hope this helps, otherwise let us know.